# Limit maker points in Polyline (to be a Line) using leaflet-geoman

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw, leaflet-geoman

I want to enable the user to draw a Line (which is a Polyline with only 2 points).

I enable drawing and the listen for `vertexadded`. When the `_rings` marker count equals 2, I disable drawing.

This feels wrong for several reasons:

1. I access a private variable `_rings`
2. Now I disable drawing but to visualise the Line I must reinitiate it in visual mode
3. To allow the user to move the 2 points of the line, I must reinitiate the Line in edit mode.
4. In edit mode the splitting of a line between 2 markers must be disabled, is this possible?

Am I missing a simpler way of doing this?

```
map.pm.enableDraw('Line', {
  snappable: true,
  snapDistance: 20,
});

map.on('pm:drawstart', (event: any) => {
  const { workingLayer } = event;
 
  workingLayer.on('pm:vertexadded', (e: any) => {
    if (workingLayer._rings[0].length >= 2) {

      map.pm.disableDraw('Line', {
        snappable: true,
        snapDistance: 20,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use `layer.getLatLngs()` instead of the variable `_rings`.
2. don't call `map.pm.disableDraw()`, finish the shape with `map.pm.Draw.Line._finishShape()` to add the drawn layer to the map
3. you can call `map.pm.enableGlobalEditMode()` to enable editing for all layers or you can enable the wanted layer with `layer.pm.enable()`
4. use the option `hideMiddleMarkers: true`

```
map.pm.setGlobalOptions({hideMiddleMarkers: true})
map.on('pm:drawstart', (event) => {
  const { workingLayer } = event;

  workingLayer.on('pm:vertexadded', (e) => {
    if (workingLayer.getLatLngs().length >= 2) {
       map.pm.Draw.Line._finishShape()
    }
  });
});
map.pm.enableDraw('Line');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/7sL02y53/